# Populate Cells with Filenames in folder, Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am using Excel 2010

I would like to insert the file name of a list of files withing a certain folder location into an Excel cell.

I.e. if the file path is: C:\Users\NAME\Documents\FolderPath

and in the FolderPath I have several files of a certain type (File001.DAT ... File00N.DAT)

How can I populate all cells within a certain column (and starting at a certain row) with the file names *.DAT ?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** I used command prompt to write file names to a text file.
In command prompt I navigated to the directory in question:

CD /Directory/Of/FIles

and then I wrote the files to a text file as follows:

dir /b *.png > FIles.txt

the flag /b gives me names only. I then copied all the names and pasted them into Excel. It's not as robust as Bruce Wayne's solution but for the time being, it did what I needed.

Comment: Dont think excel-formula will cut it for you.  I think this is squarely in the VBA domain.

Comment: Use `Dir`: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dir.php

Comment: Look up the `Dir` VBA function - This might help start you on your way.... http://stackoverflow.com/q/10380312/1693085 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/10382861/1693085

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just retrieve the output from a DIR command via the standard output stream. Much faster than `Dir$()` and no need for any loops!:

```
Sub Foo()

Dim strFolderName   As String
Dim strFileType     As String
Dim pasteRange      As Range
Dim returnVals      As Variant

'// set parameters, change as required
strFolderName = "C:\Users\NAME\Documents\FolderPath\"
strFileType = "*.DAT"
Set pasteRange = Range("C5")

'// retrieve output of DIR command from CMD.exe
returnVals = Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & strFolderName & _
                strFileType & """ /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ".")

'// Display results in chosen column
pasteRange.Resize(UBound(returnVals) + 1, 1).value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(returnVals)

End Sub
```

Comment: I like this approach, I have been trying to read it and figure out each line. One line that I don't understand (and coincidently enough) doesn't work is under the comment '// Display results in chosen column     I am getting a Runtime error '13' Type mismatch. Does this have something to do with an array not matching up? @macro-man

Comment: are you placing the results into a single column? (is the code _exactly_ the same as I posted above or have you changed something?)

Comment: I changed the directory path to my directory only i.e. C:\Users\NAME\Documents\FolderPath\ That is all I changed

Comment: My apologies, I failed to include the final \ at the end of the directory path. It works as expected now. I am going to analysis, make adjustments and post a new thread with any troubles. Thank you!!!

Comment: No worries, don't forget to mark as the answer if it helped.

Comment: Not sure how to do that; I up voted it though. That's the only button I see.

Comment: Just under the vote buttons on the left there will be a gray tick, you click this and it will turn green to confirm you've marked as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and simple way is to use a loop that just checks the extension of each file in a directory:

```
Sub t()
Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
Dim i&

file = Dir("C:\Users\me\Desktop\")
i = 1
While (file <> "")
    Debug.Print Right(file, 3)
      If Right(file, 3) = "dat" Then
         Cells(i, 1).Value = "found " & file
         i = i + 1
      End If
     file = Dir
  Wend
End Sub
```

Just adjust the `Cells(i,1)` as necessary.

Comment: Going to try this, thanks! For the time being, what I did was the following:     Navigate to the directory in question using CMD and CD. I.e. CD /Locaton/To/Directory then I wrote the files to a Txt file like so: dir /b *.png > FIles.txt         I then copied all the names in the list and pasted them into Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Another way - although the `EnumerateFiles` function is basically the same as BruceWaynes.

```
Sub PopulateSheet()

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim colFiles As Collection
    Dim vFile As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'This will find the last row in column A, but
        'can use a static number or any other method to return a row number.
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set colFiles = New Collection

        'Remember to put the final \ in the file path.
        EnumerateFiles "C:\Users\NAME\Documents\FolderPath\", _
            "*.DAT", colFiles

        For Each vFile In colFiles
            .Cells(lRow, 1) = Mid(vFile, InStrRev(vFile, "\") + 1)
            lRow = lRow + 1
        Next vFile

    End With

End Sub

'//Places all file names with FileSpec extension into a collection.
Sub EnumerateFiles(ByVal sDirectory As String, _
    ByVal sFileSpec As String, _
    ByRef cCollection As Collection)

    Dim sTemp As String

    sTemp = Dir$(sDirectory & sFileSpec)
    Do While Len(sTemp) > 0
        cCollection.Add sDirectory & sTemp
        sTemp = Dir$
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: This code works quite well. I am currently investing time into this by trying to learn from it. Thanks! I do have two questions however, I will start with the most important first: How can I remove the file extension in the generation of file names? I tried removing several factors in the code to no avail. As for the second question, I will attempt to create a file dialog box to get the files independently and if no success, will post a new thread.

Comment: Btw, I was able to find how to remove file extensions using command prompt. It is as follows:  dir /b /O:N *.DAT  > flist.txt 
for %i in (*.DAT) do @echo %~ni >> fileNames.txt

Comment: Two ways I can think of to remove the extension:  `mid(vfile,instrrev(vFile,"\")+1,instrrev(vfile,".")-instrrev(vfile,"\")-1)` or use a separate function: `Public Function GetBaseName(ByVal strFullName As String) As String: Dim oFSO As Object: Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"): GetBaseName = oFSO.GetBaseName(strFullName): End Function`

Comment: I always forget about the Dir parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done without VBA though you do need a Macro-enabled workbook:

1. Create a new Excel spreadsheet and save is as macro enabled (*.xlsm)
2. On the Formulas tab click "Define Name" define a new name.
3. Set Name: to "MyFiles" and Refers to: to `=FILES(".\*.xls?")`
4. Starting with cell A1 enter a column of numbers from 1 to 20 (or so)
5. Enter this `=IFERROR(INDEX(MyFiles,A1), "")` in cell B1
6. Copy cell B1 to the down the column alongside the list of numbers, the reference in the formula should update automatically

You should get a list of the first 20 or so files.

The parameter for the FILES function is just a standard DOS wildcard pattern so you might want `C:\Users\NAME\Documents\FolderPath\*.DAT` instead of `.\*.xls?`.